# asp.net dynamic insert rows into middle of table

Tags: asp.net, tablerow

I want to add a few dynamic rows right in the middle of a table which is otherwise defined in static markup.  Unfortunately, [Web.UI.Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table_methods.aspx) has no exposed AddAt method.

It looks like I can dynamically [AddAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rowcontrolcollection.addat.aspx) on a Web.UI.ControlCollection, and it looks like internally, Web.UI.WebControls.Table has a [RowControlCollection.AddAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rowcontrolcollection.addat.aspx) method, but MSDN says that it's "not intended to be used directly from your code".  Is this safe, will it work?

An alternative approach is to just nest another table inside a single placeholder TableRow, but the table is used for position/style :( so nesting a table in a row is going to cause major style problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use _table.Rows.Insert(index,row)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if MSDN is contradicting itself or not, but Table.Rows.AddAt == TableRowCollection.AddAt which is [perfectly acceptable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerowcollection.addat.aspx).